# In matplotlib, how to change the linewidth of the axis grid using mplstyle sheet?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

For the following example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5)), columns=list("abcde"))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()).mul(100), axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
df.T.plot.barh(
    stacked=True,
    ax=ax,
)
[ax.spines[x].set_visible(False) for x in ax.spines]

ax.grid()
```

which look as:

[image]

I'd like to be able to adjust the gridlines so that they're flush with the right side of the plot as they are with the left.

Here they're beyond the bars:

[image]

Here they're flush:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.set_xlim(0,100.1)
```

Just before the `ax.grid()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry to move the goalposts, but how would this affect legend placement? Typically I would have legend either to the right or below the graph, rather than within it like this.

Comment: If you want automatic, you can also adjust the "margins" to be zero: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_margins.html